Resize2fs ext4 (md4p1 500GB) does not see increased disk size on mdadm raid1 array (md4 2TB) in ubuntu 24.04 system
I have a software raid array made up of two new enlarged SSD disks from ~500 GB to 2 TB. I have moved to the new larger disks in and resynched the arrays. For the life of me I can figure out how to resize the ext4 file system. Md raid array is running fine, just can't access my new disk space. I have backups and this is not a boot array.
When I run resize2fs i get this:
# resize2fs /dev/md4p1
resize2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
The filesystem is already 122062592 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

# resize2fs /dev/md4
resize2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/md4
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

# mdadm -D /dev/md4
/dev/md4:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Sat Nov 13 16:07:31 2021
Raid Level : raid1
Array Size : 1953382488 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1953382488 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Sun Oct 20 09:01:28 2024
State : active
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

Name : ubuntu-server:4
UUID : 4e46069e:13bfbbb0:01aae036:be89c33e
Events : 94685

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
4       8       48        0      active sync   /dev/sdd
3       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb

# lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
sdb         linux_raid_member   1.8T                               ubuntu-server:4
└─md4                           1.8T
  └─md4p1   ext4              465.6G /mnt/SSD-raid

sdd         linux_raid_member   1.8T                               ubuntu-server:4
└─md4                           1.8T
  └─md4p1   ext4              465.6G /mnt/SSD-raid

